# Why do my images flicker as I scroll through a datagridview?

Tags: c#, image, windows-forms-designer

The datagridview is being filled with information in a table of a local database, and the images are being loaded with the file path. Here's the relevant code:

```
    private void Btn_ViewPicture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conImg = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (localdb)\\MSSqlLocalDB; Initial Catalog = C:\\USERS\\MyName\\DOCUMENTS\\SKYRIMARCHITECTURE.MDF; Integrated Security = True");
        SqlCommand cmdImg = new SqlCommand("Select ObjectID, ObjectName, ObjectImagePath from Images", conImg);
        SqlDataAdapter daIMG = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdImg);
        DataTable imageDT = new DataTable();
        daIMG.Fill(imageDT);
        imageDT.Columns.Add("ItemPicture", Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"));
        foreach (DataRow drow in imageDT.Rows)
        {
            drow["ItemPicture"] = File.ReadAllBytes(drow["ObjectImagePath"].ToString());
        }
        ViewImage.DataSource = imageDT;
    }
```

In order to gather the images, I'm using a screenshot feature in a program called NifSkope. It just takes a screenshot of the item, then lets you save it to a specific folder on your computer. From there, I'm using a batch image resizer to resize the images, because the size that Nifskope chooses for the images is way too big. The bulk resizer saves the images in a different folder. Then I load the images by pasting the file paths into the table in the database.
I did bind the columns in the datagridview with the columns in the database by setting the column data property to the name of each respective column in the database table.
I expected to be able to scroll through images, specifically images sized at 812x507 pixels, without it flickering. It's almost as though scrolling causes the datagridview to reload, but I can't see why that would be.

Comment: `MessageBox.Show("ex.Message");` <-- 

Comment: I know that's not why, because it flickered before I had that try catch block too. Don't worry, I'll make the message more specific later.

Comment: How many pictures?

Comment: At the moment, 178. But there will be a total of 3347 when I'm done. I just haven't gathered all the images yet (to be clear, I'm only adding new rows in the database table when I have the corresponding image all ready to go.)